# Multilanguage category structure - standard vs. normalization?

Tags: mysql

I'm building a multilingual application and I need some advice on how to structure the table.

Basically I have a category table based on nested set. There are 4 languages and I plan to enlarge this up to 8 languages in the future.

Currently I plan a table like this;

```
[category]
id
lft
rgt
title_en
title_fr
title_de
title_es
```

If I go for the normalization way;

```
[category]
id
lft
rgt

[category_lang]
cid
lang
title
```

My main concerns are speed and size. Which way is more optimal?